# What is the impact of not having synchronized Nuget packages between Xamarin Forms PCL + iOS + Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, nuget, shared-libraries

Xamarin forms allows for a shared PCL library that also is able to have nuget packages applied to it.  What is the impact of having non-synchronized packages in iOS, the PCL, and Android?

At build time which package takes priority?

How can I update a single Nuget package across all projects, without having to click them all.  (Update all packages is a no-go for me, I require some older libraries)

Answer (score 0):

Majority of the information you're seeking is within the NuGet/Microsoft docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/dependency-resolution

As for non-synchronized packages, it can be quite troublesome as mixing versions is usually a bad idea. This can be a PCL API that invokes the wrong Project specific API. In my experience, do not mix and match any versions. This includes Xamarin.Forms, Google Play Services, Support Libraries. Make sure they are all consistent across the board or else you'll have a bad time.

Updating the same NuGet package across all projects can be as simple as using the NuGet Package Manager at the `.sln` level(Right click a solution that includes all the projects and use `Manage NuGet Packages`). Be wary that dependencies need updating as well, so ensure you are updating the `parent` package so it can handle the dependency resolution.